# Converting a lot of invalid HTML to valid HTML

Tags: html, validation

I am refurbishing a site that contains a lot of invalid HTML that looks little like this:

```
<p>I was written by someone who knows a little, but not enough, 
   HTML, & now I need to be cleaned.</p>
```

I need to be able to convert this HTML to make it valid. The conversion needs to be smart and not muck with the content. Is there something out there that will easily do this job on a large scale?

Comment: I'm probably going to kick myself, but what is the problem with that HTML? :)

Comment: Agree. I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Unless OP really meant what he wrote: "that looks little like this" instead of what I interpreted: "that looks *a* little like this".

Comment: `&` characters need to be `&amp;` in HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) might be of some help.

Comment: Yes, maybe. I will fiddle with it and see what I can come up with. Thanks!